# Sign in in a rails app with Devise and token_authenticatable : "401 unauthorized"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, authentication, devise

I am trying to build an API to login to my rails app with Devise and an authenticatable_token.
I created a SessionsController in my API module and wrote the following code to sign_in :

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

      def create  
        resource = warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#new")
        sign_in(resource_name, resource) 
        if current_user  
          if !current_user.authentication_token  
            current_user.reset_authentication_token! 
          end
          render json: {success: true, auth_token: resource.authentication_token, email: resource.email}
        else 
          invalid_login_attempt
        end 
      end

      protected

      def invalid_login_attempt
        warden.custom_failure!
        render json: {success: false, message: "Error with your login or password"}, status: 401
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the app raises a 401 when I use the login without any token.

```
RestClient.post "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/sign_in", {user: {email: "tester@test.biz", password: "FILTERED"}}.to_json, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
```

But if I set the token that was provided by the sign up method it works :

```
response_json = RestClient.post "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/sign_in?auth_token=#{@token}", {user: {email: "tester@test.biz", password: "FILTERED"}}.to_json, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
```

So why this ? Is it possible to disable the token authentication process when performing a sign in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise controllers doesn't work out of the box when you use the json format, you'll have to do one of the following :

- remove your content type => json and the accept => json directives
- add config.navigational_formats = [:html, :json] to your devise config file
- overload the controller to handle that format in you need a specific response, which is quite common

You can get a working example there http://jessehowarth.com/devise

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed the instructions on your website but I still get a 401. Moreover I get a 500 with error `undefined method `split' for :failure:Symbol'` from the `resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => :failure)`. I also removed the content type and accept directives from my request and add the navigational_formats.

Comment: Actually it is the `warden.authenticate!` that raises the 401.

Comment: I finally succeeded. My errors were caused by a wrong route. I had to use localhost:3000/api/v1/sign_in instead of api/v1/users/sign_in. By the way your link and your advices in the configuration helped me to get the things working correctly.

Comment: That link is no longer available. Is there any salient code you can provide in your response as an example?

Comment: Ah indeed, the author wiped his website. A quick google search yielded http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/ which illustrates it in the same way.